# How Can I Make A Command Prompt Hang?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, freeze

**Yes, I know you are probably going to complain saying it's a bad thing to do, but I want to do it anyway!**

I am creating a batch program and at the end, I need it to hang and not accept user input. I know one method is just creating an infinite loop of:

```
    :pause
        pause > nul
        goto pause
```

but I don't think that's a great choice. Although I need it to hang, I need to to be able to be closed via the red 'X' close button at the top of the window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it? The window should close. Another option is `sleep 1000000`.

Comment: @tdelaney Does `sleep 1000000` not accept `Ctrl + C` though?

Comment: nearly unknown command `waitfor /?`

Comment: @Stephan They both accept `Ctrl + C`

Comment: @Stephan `waitfor /?` does give a response

Comment: What @stephan meant was something like **waitfor "something"** ..  It won't terminate until you do something like **waitfor /si "something"** from another console window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  It redirects `< NUL` into self to prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from breaking, and uses `start /b /wait` to suppress the "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" prompts.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

>NUL (echo(%* | findstr "\<hang\>" && waitfor redX)

rem // *** PUT YOUR MAIN SCRIPT HERE ***
echo End of line.
rem // ******* END MAIN SCRIPT *********
call :hang
goto :EOF

:hang
start /b /wait "" "%~f0" hang ^<NUL
```

On the initial launch of the script, the `echo(%* | findstr "\<hang\>" >NUL` line looks for a script argument of "hang".  If found, the script executes the `waitfor` command.

Normally, `waitfor` can be broken with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  But since the usual behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is defeated by `start /b` and `<NUL`, the hanging effect is achieved unless a user does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> or sends the answering `waitfor` signal.

The red X still works, though.

Comment: Great answer! That would be useful to others, but not me unfortunately. I have a big program and I'm testing for something, then, if it exists, hanging the cmd.

Comment: So why not `if problem exists ( call :hang )` then?